# Setting a button's alphaHitTestMinimumTreshold results into no call to Button.OnPointerDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, alpha, raycasting

I want to create a button that has a custom shape in Unity.

I created a default UI>Button object and set it's `Image` to the following sprite:
[image]

It doesn't show it on this website, but the circle is the only part of this image that is transparent. It's a .png sprite.

When I set this as the sprite for my button, I could click on the entire rect transform of this sprite to activate the button using my button's [OnPointerDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html) method and un-hide some other sprites around it:

```
public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
    Debug.Log("Foo");
}
```

Each time any part of the sprite was clicked, transparent or not, "Foo" would print.

Now I set the button [alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold.html) to 0.5:

`GetComponent<Button>().image.alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold = .5f;`

And as the docs suggest, I disabled atlassing...

[image]

...and enabled read/write for the sprite:

[image]

Yet now, when I click the button in my scene.. nothing happens. No matter where I click, "Foo" doesn't print anymore.

Then I tried changing the alphaHitTestMinimumThreshold to a lot of different values. Again, the *entire* button was not clickable anymore. If I don't touch the alphaHitTestMinimumTreshold at all however, my "Foo" prints again.

Why does changing alphaHitTestMinimumTreshold to *any* value make my OnPointerDown method to never be called?

Answer (score 1):

So after 12 hours of messing around with all sorts of options, I found out that there were 3+ consecutive issues causing this behaviour.

If you ever run into your transparent buttons not working, be sure to try the following steps:

- Make sure read/write is enabled in the texture import settings
- Try if setting the Sprite Mode Mesh Type to Full Rect helps (sometimes the button's hitbox is off)
- Disable atlassing under Project Settings > Editor > Sprite Packer > Mode
- ..and finally what did the trick for me: if you're working in a prefab that's nested inside another prefab (say your have a prefab for your button and then another prefab for your UI canvas/contents), remove the nested prefab from the parent prefab (aka remove the button prefab from the UI prefab), and just add it back in again. It was that freaking simple for me.

I triple checked whether my nested button prefab differed from the button prefab blueprint, and it didn't. But somehow, removing it from the UI prefab and adding it back in again solved my problem with a large sprinkle of magic.

Answer (score 0):

With transparency buttons, I found that detection improves when the image is a child of the button object. So hierarchy is Canvas>Button>Image.

Answer (score 0):

I know, old thread, but it came up so heres my solution:

It did all of the suggestions, but it didn't work.

HOWEVER,
What finally worked for me, was TO SPECIFY THE RIGHT SIZE. My game Object was elongated, but the sprite had "preserve aspect ratio" ticked. I just didn't bother to size it properly.
So when you have an image, set the size of the gameObject to the right dimensions.